# Is there any function to find dynamic element on App page using Appium?

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, appium, xcuitest

I am developing UI test automation for `iOS App`, By click on the button (`XCUIElementTypeButton`), it actually add buttons in `XCUIElementTypeCell` on App page. 
Where do I find dynamically added buttons (or other elements) on App page?

> Note: 
>   - This is not hybrid app, So this App does not have web page.

By changing App page and come back to original page, Appium always find dynamic elements.

I need help to find any function or method to reload all `XCUIElement` without changing page.

Comment: Wasn't the driver's `PageSource` property supposed to load the new content automatically? I can't imagine you would need to reload the app window before the appium driver is able to find that new element.

Comment: [This](https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-cant-locate-dynamic-generated-elements-on-ios-native-app/17339) post on the appium forum seems to be related.